# Display result on Select

Tags: php, javascript

i am using below `code`, Its displaying the ??? only in place of `result`. Can you please help me out to correct the `error` in the below form ? message is displaying the blank result like in ?? format. any help ? --

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
  <tr>
    <td width="12%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="2%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="2%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="2%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="16%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="66%">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="images/australia1.jpg" width="132" height="70"></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><select name="select">
      <option>Select Course Type</option>
      <option>Under Graduate</option>
      <option>Post Graduate</option>
    </select>
    </td>
    <td><div id="message"></div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>

</table>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
var messages = {
    Under Graduate: 'UG text is here',
    Post Graduate: 'PG text is here'
}
$('select').change(function() {
    $('#message').text(messages[$(this).val()]);
});​
</script>
```

Comment: Its really hard to understand what your problem is. Could you please try to describe your problem more clearly?

Comment: How is the page encrypted? do you have this meta in your header? `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`

Comment: Try with `$('#message').html(messages[$(this).val()]);`

Comment: simple the above is displaying the result. any help ? Its should display the `UG text is here` after selecting the `Under Graduate`, but it giving ??? as results.----

Comment: in place of result ? i dont see any place of result.. can u explain more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
var messages = {
    under: 'UG text is here',
    post: 'PG text is here'
}
$('select').change(function() {
    if($(this).val() != '')
        $('#message').text(messages[$(this).val()]);
});​
</script>

<select name="select">
  <option value="">Select Course Type</option>
  <option value="under">Under Graduate</option>
  <option value="post">Post Graduate</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I am using below code, its not showing results-- really afraid now for me `<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
var messages = {
    under: 'UG text is here',
    post: 'PG text is here'
}
$('select').change(function() {
    if($(this).val() != '')
        $('#message').html(messages[$(this).val()]);
});?
</script>



<select name="select">
  <option value="">Select Course Type</option>
  <option value="under">Under Graduate</option>
  <option value="post">Post Graduate</option>
</select>
 <td><div id="message"></div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​</td>
`

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax errors in your message object. You need to use quotes around keys that have spaces in them:

```
var messages = {
    'Under Graduate': 'UG text is here',
    'Post Graduate': 'PG text is here'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you just missing `value` attribute and use one-word identifier

```
<option vale="under_graduate">Under Graduate</option>

var messages = {
    under_graduate: 'UG text is here',
    val1: 'PG text is here'
}
</script>
```

Comment: i don't think is the value.. since, if the value attribute is not specified, the content will be passed as a value instead.

Comment: Dreamveawer showing an error, `The document's current encoding can not correctly save all the characters within the document you may want to change it to UTF-8 or an encoding that support spacial characters in this document.` I think its causes issues :(

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">


  $('#select').change(function() {

    var selectVal = $('#select :selected').val();
     $(#message).text(selectVal);

});
   </script>
```

and replace

```
    <select name="select">
```

by

```
   <select id="select">
```